# NullPointerException for RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I have been recently starting to study and practice development for Android with Kotlin, for that I have been using a book from a Humble bundle from around a year ago, however until recently I was able to start on it, following each chapter there are certain apps to work on, for Recycler View there is an example with an app for Notes, after coding all clases, methods and functions needed I stood with this error and after checking multiple sources I am still unable to solve this, here is the line of code for the Main file

```
package com.gree.notas

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
//private var notaTemporal = Notas()
private val listaNotas = ArrayList<Notas>()
private var recyclerView1: RecyclerView? = null
private var adapter: AdaptadorNotas? = null

fun crearNuevaNota(n: Notas){
    //notaTemporal = n
    listaNotas.add(n)
    adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun mostrarNota(notaMostrar: Int){
    val dialogo = MostrarNota()
    dialogo.enviarNotaSeleccionada(listaNotas[notaMostrar])
    dialogo.show(supportFragmentManager, "")
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

    findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener { view ->
        val dialogo = NuevaNota()
        dialogo.show(supportFragmentManager,"")
    }

    recyclerView1 = findViewById<View>(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
    adapter = AdaptadorNotas(this, listaNotas)
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
    recyclerView1!!.layoutManager = layoutManager
    recyclerView1!!.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    recyclerView1!!.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))
    recyclerView1!!.adapter = adapter
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> true
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the code for the Adapter class

```
package com.gree.notas

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class AdaptadorNotas(private val mainActivity: MainActivity, private val listaNotas: List<Notas>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorNotas.ListItemHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListItemHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.lista, parent, false)

    return ListItemHolder(itemView)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    if(listaNotas != null){
        return listaNotas.size
    }
    return -1
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListItemHolder, position: Int) {
    val nota = listaNotas!![position]
    holder.titulo.text = nota.titulo

    holder.descripcion.text = nota.descripcion!!.substring(0, 15)
    when{
        nota.idea -> holder.estado.text = mainActivity.resources.getString(R.string.texto_idea)
        nota.importante -> holder.estado.text = mainActivity.resources.getString(R.string.texto_importante)
        nota.porHacer -> holder.estado.text = mainActivity.resources.getString(R.string.porhacer_texto)
    }
}

inner class ListItemHolder(view: View) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener{
        internal var titulo = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.textViewTitle) as TextView
        internal var descripcion = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.textViewDescription) as TextView
        internal var estado =  view.findViewById<View>(R.id.textViewStatus) as TextView
        init {
            view.isClickable = true
            view.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            mainActivity.mostrarNota(adapterPosition)
        }
    }
 }
```

If somebody could help me find the root of the issue or show me what I should be looking for debugging and finding the right information for this NullPointerException [Exception on Build log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMdar.jpg), will be really helpful

Comment: Debug at line 42 the casting is null where you added wrong check  as this !!

Comment: You set your RecyclerView to null while initializing it in line 17 of your code in MainAcitivity. Like the error said, you cant cast null to non-null type. Maybe using lateinit in front of var could fix this issue.

Comment: Also since you don't need RecyclerView outside of onCreate in MainActivity, you can simply just call it there as it is. private var recyclerView1: RecyclerView? = findViewById<View>(R.id.recyclerView)

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace points to this line:

> ```
> recyclerView1 = findViewById<View>(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
> ```

The error ("`null` cannot be cast to non-null type") means that `findViewById()` is returning `null`, so the cast (`as RecyclerView`) fails.

This means that there is no view with the id `@+id/recyclerView` in your layout. You have called `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`, so make sure that a view with this id exists in `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think that may be the issue as the @+id/recyclerView is not specifically in that layout, it is included on another layout named firstfragment.xml and included on the content_main and then with fragment showned on activity_main.xml with this line of code `<include layout="@layout/content_main" />`